# No [New..]>[Activity] on Android Studio 0.4.2

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently updated my android studio to 0.4.2, and I can't find 'create new activity' menu.

In older version, I could find 'Activity' in [New]-[Android Component].

But now, I just see a dialog window, which has [New App Widget], [New Blank Fragment]... etc,
but not Activity.

Where is the menu that creating an Activity?

---

I think it's not android studio's problem and my perference has problem.
Here is the menu which shows up when I clicked [New..] button.(I wanted to attach the image, but I have not enough reputation.)

[Java Class], [Module], [File], [Package], [Android Component], [Image Asset], [package-info.java] | [HTML file]

How can I reveal the [Activity] button?

Answer (score 0):

I also have 0.4.2 and I can create a new activity by File | New... | Activity

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on the Java package in the Project view where the new activity class should be created and choose **New** > **Activity**. Or, if the package is selected in the Project view, then **File** menu > **New** >  **Activity**.

Comment: then I think it's not android studio's bug... but I have no new>Activity. All I got is 1. Java Class 2. Module 3. File 4. Package 5. Android Component 6. Image Asset 7. package-info.java | 8. HTML File

Comment: Is this in an Android application or library module? Does it have a build.gradle file?

Comment: When I right-clicked a package which have Activity class files and mouse-over [New], the same menu opened(except [HTML Files]). // Actually I don't use gradle. I think gradle is necessary, but don't know how to use it.